# Why I'm getting a timezone not on TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

I'm sending timezone identifiers to our backend, and I'm facing a problem because sometimes I'm sending deprecated ones.

The problem is that this deprecated timezone is get from the phone system.
For instance, selecting "Washington D.C" on time settings I get "US/Eastern" when I call `TimeZone.current.identifier`.

Furthermore, if I call `TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers` I get a list of ~400 items, but "US/Eastern" is not there!

How is it even possible that `TimeZone.current.identifier` is returning a timezone not in `knownTimeZoneIdentifiers`?

Comment: What is the problem with `US/Eastern`?

Comment: It works for me here `let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "US/Eastern")!` it gives me -5hs

Comment: Btw US/Eastern is too generic. I down know why it is not returning a specific city.

Comment: @Sweeper php.net says it's deprecated... https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

Comment: @LeoDabus yes it works but I'm just curious about how the system can return something not inside `knownTimeZoneIdentifiers` if calling to its selected timezone

Comment: I just tested it. Leaving the time zone on automatic, my phone picks New York (I'm in the DC metro area) and returns an identifier of "America/New_York" (which is in the list of known identifiers.) I get the same if I pick the time zone for New York manually. If I pick Washington DC, I get "US/Eastern" as you report. It seems like it should map from any city in the same time zone to one of the known identifiers.